# jQuery: fading out 2 elements, when 1 has been clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadeout

I have a PHP/PostgreSQL/Oracle-script which displays links as "tags", which can be clicked to display only the database records matching that "tag". And then I have an "X" near every "tag", so that the user can hide uninteresting "tags":

[image]

I would like to add a fade out effect to the both elements (the "tag" and the "X") - when the "X" has been clicked. So I am trying:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
a.hide {
        color:#3E6D8E;
        background-color: #E0EAF1;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #3E6D8E;
        border-right: 1px solid #7F9FB6;
        padding: 3px 4px 3px 4px;
        margin: 2px 2px 2px 0;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 90%;
        line-height: 2.4;
        white-space: nowrap;
}

a.hide:hover {
        background-color: #e7540c;
        color: #E0EAF1;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #A33B08;
        border-right: 1px solid #A33B08;
        text-decoration: none;
}

a.filter {
        color:#3E6D8E;
        background-color: #E0EAF1;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #3E6D8E;
        border-right: 1px solid #7F9FB6;
        padding: 3px 4px 3px 4px;
        margin: 2px 2px 2px 0;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 90%;
        line-height: 2.4;
        white-space: nowrap;
}

a.filter:hover {
        background-color: #3E6D8E;
        color: #E0EAF1;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #37607D;
        border-right: 1px solid #37607D;
        text-decoration: none;
}
</style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('a.hide').click(function () {
                $(this).fadeOut('fast');
        });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Please click on
<a class="filter" href="?filter=1">Tag 1</a><a
class="hide" href="?hide=1">X</a></p>

<p>Please click on
<a class="filter" href="?filter=2">Tag 2</a><a
class="hide" href="?hide=2">X</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

However I have 2 problems:

1. When my PHP-script is quick, then I don't see any fade effect at all. (This is a minor problem, because my real script is far from being quick **:-)** )
2. I only manage to fade out the clicked "X". How can I fade out the "tag" on the left from it? (And I can't use #id here, because my real script has hundreds of such "tags")

Please push the jQuery newbie in correct direction!
Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`.prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) to get the previous sibling, then [`.andSelf()`](http://api.jquery.com/andSelf/) to again include the `X` itself, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('a.hide').click(function () {
    $(this).prev().andSelf().fadeOut('fast');
  });
});
```

If you want to fade out the "Please click on..." as well, fade out the `<p>` by climbing up to it with [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('a.hide').click(function () {
    $(this).closest('p').fadeOut('fast');
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. Why doesn't $(this).prev().andSelf().hide('explode', 1000); work?

Comment: @Alexander - are you including the jQuery UI library? it's needed (at least the effects portion) to support this...effects like `explode` aren't in core.

Comment: I see, thanks. Is hide() not in the core as well? Because it fails too (the "tag" grows bigger and is not hidden).

Comment: Also for my real slow script I have now the problem that an "X" link can be clicked twice, while the user is waiting. I must somehow replace the "X"s anchor by a "#", but I'm not sure how...

Answer (score 1):

And this way will fix the minor problem of not seeing the fadeout...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('a.hide').each(function (i, anchor) {
    var $anchor = $(anchor);
    var oldHref = $anchor.attr('href');    
    $anchor.attr('href', '#');
    $anchor.click(function(){
       $anchor.prev().andSelf().fadeOut('fast', function(){
         window.location.href = oldHref;
       });
    });    
  });
});
```

Basically, it removes the href and replaces it with a # so it won't navigate before the event is fired.  After the fadeout, the user is navigated to the original href.

Comment: Thank you. What does each() mean above? Will it go through all the hundred "tags" at my web page?

Comment: Yep. It will iterate all the matched elements from $('a.hide').  The function argument is then executed for each iteration and the element is passed in.  In my example I named that parameter 'anchor', but you could name it whatever.  The 'i' parameter is just and index.

Answer (score 0):

Because duration is first parameter of hide()
you should use it like this :

```
hide(1000, 'explode');
```