# jQuery: clicked link should fade out, do not accept further clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, fade, fadeout

with [Stackoverflow users help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4517602/jquery-fading-out-2-elements-when-1-has-been-clicked) I have now links, which fade out when clicked:

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
a.toggle {
        color:#3E6D8E;
        background-color: #E0EAF1;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #3E6D8E;
        border-right: 1px solid #7F9FB6;
        padding: 3px 4px 3px 4px;
        margin: 2px 2px 2px 0;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 90%;
        line-height: 2.4;
        white-space: nowrap;
}

a.toggle:hover {
        background-color: #e7540c;
        color: #E0EAF1;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #A33B08;
        border-right: 1px solid #A33B08;
        text-decoration: none;
}

a.filter {
        color:#3E6D8E;
        background-color: #E0EAF1;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #3E6D8E;
        border-right: 1px solid #7F9FB6;
        padding: 3px 4px 3px 4px;
        margin: 2px 2px 2px 0;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 90%;
        line-height: 2.4;
        white-space: nowrap;
}

a.filter:hover {
        background-color: #3E6D8E;
        color: #E0EAF1;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #37607D;
        border-right: 1px solid #37607D;
        text-decoration: none;
}
</style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('a.toggle').click(function () {
                $(this).prev().andSelf().fadeOut('fast');
        });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Please click on
<a class="filter" href="?filter=1">Tag 1</a><a class="toggle" href="/?toggle=2">X</a></p>

<p>Please click on
<a class="filter" href="?filter=2">Tag 2</a><a class="toggle" href="/?toggle=2">X</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

But I have now the new problem, that when the "X" link has been clicked and it starts to fade out, then it can still be clicked again and this is bad for my script - because "X" shouldn't completely removes a "tag", but just move it under a hidden section as you can see in this screenshot. And then subsequent click should move it back:

[image]

How could I prevent subsequent clicks please?

I probably should call **$(this).prev().andSelf().fadeOut('fast').attr('href', XXX);** ? But what should be the new value here?

Thank you! Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to what Mike said, however just instead of worry about the unbinding, let jQuery do it for you:

```
    $('a.toggle').one("click", function () {
            $(this).prev().andSelf().fadeOut('fast');
    });
```

This means the function will fire once, and then unbind it self.

Comment: That is a bit more concise.  Wasn't aware the function existed. xD

Comment: Neither was I until SO came into my life ;)

Comment: Shorthand for StackOverflow :)

Comment: SO is a great site! (they should add a badge for flattery)

Answer (score 1):

You could **unbind** (remove) the click event as soon as it is fired, ensuring it only runs once.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('a.toggle').click(function () {
                $(this).unbind("click").prev().andSelf().fadeOut('fast');
        });
});
```

Comment: The only problem with this, it would unbind any other click event handlers the OP might apply/applied to the link.

Comment: @Psytronic. It should not do that as you are only unbinding the click event of "this", which will be the single anchor that was clicked.  The only conflict will come if he expects to bind other methods to this element's click event.

Comment: sorry, I missed out that vital information, I did mean to say "applied to the link". I'll update, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use '`#`', and just make your click handler return false if the `href` is `#`.

Comment: Thanks, so I should call $(this).prev().andSelf().fadeOut('fast').attr('href', '#'); But how do I make the click handler remove false? I'm still studying jQuery docs...

Comment: Just add a `return false;` at the end of your function. That being said, `Mike`'s solution is a better one (using `unbind`).

Comment: Actually this doesn't work because the underlying PHP-script doesn't get called at all - i.e. no click happens, just the element disappears

Comment: Right, my mistake - you'd need to test the `href` of the link that was clicked, and only return false if it was `#`.